# Is there a way to get the CharmsBar Width?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps

I would like to resize some controls of my App when the CharmsBar (specially the SearchPane) opens. I have made some tests and the width is usually 343 but sometimes it is greater (it depends on the size of the screen, not on the resolution. At least, using the emulator).

Does somebody know if there is a programatic method to get that value?

Comment: It sounds like you are really tying you UI to something that is meant to overlay your app - I suspect it's the same on all screen sizes, but you would have to test portrait mode, and different DPIs. A fluid app probably should need this sort of info tho.

Comment: As I said, the tests that I made shows that width may vary between screen sizes. For example, the search pane width in a 10.6" 1920x1080 screen is different from a 23" 1920x1080 screen.

Comment: I think it's always 346.

Comment: The size of the Charms bar is subject to change in future versions of Windows. Even if there were a way to get its size, you won't know *where* the Charms bar appears. (Sometimes it appears on the left.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The width is always 346 *but* you have to apply the zoom factor to obtain the real width in pixels. And this can be achieved using:

```
double SearchPaneWidth() {
        var scale = Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayProperties.ResolutionScale;
        switch (scale) {
            case Windows.Graphics.Display.ResolutionScale.Scale100Percent:
                return 1.0 * 346;
            case Windows.Graphics.Display.ResolutionScale.Scale140Percent:
                return 1.4 * 346;
            case Windows.Graphics.Display.ResolutionScale.Invalid:
                return 1.8 * 346;
            default:
                throw new Exception("Unknown resolution scale");
        }
    }
```